# How to specify the search column with VLOOKUP?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

With this table:

```
1   a    aaa
2   3    bbb
4   d    ddd
3   c    ccc
```

I'd like to search a value in the first column, and get the second column value.

Of course, this works:

```
=VLOOKUP(1; A1:B4; 2)     => a
=VLOOKUP(2; A1:B4; 2)     => 3
=VLOOKUP(4; A1:B4; 2)     => d
```

But, problem:

- `=VLOOKUP(3; A1:B4; 2)` gives `3`
- `=VLOOKUP(3; A1:C4; 3)` gives `bbb`

**This means `3` has been searched ... in the second column. Why?**

It seems that `=VLOOKUP(...; A1:B3; 2)` searches in *all columns* of A1:B3.

**Question: how to specify that I only want to search the pattern in the first column?**

Note: `=VLOOKUP(...; A1:A4; 2)` doesn't work and gives `#REF!` because then the third argument `2` mentions a column out of the A1:A4 range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/4/0/340f95a5-33cd-45a5-8701-7efa0cf82daf/AF102038056_en-us_xl_qrc_vlookup_troubleshooter.pdf) is a link you might find useful for reference purposes.

`VLOOKUP` only searches in the first column. You've left the `range_lookup` parameter (the 4th argument) blank, so it defaults to `TRUE`. When you use `TRUE` the order of the numbers in your first column matters. The quickest way to solve your issue is to use `FALSE` (exact match only) e.g.

```
=VLOOKUP(3,A1:B4,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `VLOOKUP only searches in the first column`: this seems wrong. Look at `=VLOOKUP(3; A1:B4; 2)` => it gives `3` meaning that `3` has been searched in the *second* column.

Comment: Another example @mikehunt3921: `=VLOOKUP(3; A1:C4; 3)` gives `bbb`. This confirms `3` has been searched in the 2nd column, instead of the 1st one. Do you confirm too?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use a combination of Index and Match instead of Vlookup, this is more flexible for data lookup.

For your example table:

```
1   a    aaa
2   3    bbb
4   d    ddd
3   c    ccc
```

`=Index(A1:C4,Match("3",A1:A4,0),3)`

or

`=Index(A:C,Match("3",A:A,0),3)`

Does the following:
Finds the first match for your reference `3` in the first column, using `match`, returning a row number of 4, then finds the value in row number 4 of column number 3 of the indexed array using  `index`

In the first example it searches a 4rx3c array, where in the second it searches an array 3 columns wide for the entire length of the worksheet.

They will both return `ccc` as answer.

If you change the column number to `2` i.e.

`=Index(A1:C4,Match("3",A1:A4,0),2)`

The answer is returned from the second column giving `c`

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @mikehunt3921 is correct:

- `VLOOKUP` only searches in the first column.
- 4th parameter as `FALSE` is the solution

My example was a coincidence, here are more details:

When the 4th parameter is missing, it defaults to `TRUE` (as explained by Mike), and then ["the closest match to the lookup value"](https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/4/0/340f95a5-33cd-45a5-8701-7efa0cf82daf/AF102038056_en-us_xl_qrc_vlookup_troubleshooter.pdf) is used.

In my example, it looks at the first column, looking for `3`. It finds 1, then 2, then 4, we're over 3, so *it stops* here (it does not look at the final row with value 3!). Since it has **not found** an exact match, it takes the closest value, i.e. `2`, whose second column is `3`. Answer 3!

---

Another example / proof that nothing is searched in the 2nd column:

```
1   a
17  3
6   d
3   c
```

`=VLOOKUP(3;A1:B4;2)` gives `a`.

Explanation: we search for 3 in the first column. Let's loop over the rows: 1, then 17, we're over 3, so we stop here. As 3 was not found, we take the closest value: 1.

The second column is `a`. Anwser: `a`.

---

**TL;DR: Always set 4th parameter as 0 / FALSE except for very specific reasons!**